# Creating UINavigationController programmatically (iOS9, ObjC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios9, xcode7

I want to create a UINavigationController programatically
and I've followed a few tutorials on the internet but I keep getting error messages even though I've followed the tutorials step by step in detail.

The error I get with my current code is the following:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'BrowserController''

And my code looks like this:

`.h`file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class BrowserController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) BrowserController *rootViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;


@end
```

`.m`file:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BrowserController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


    self.rootViewController = [[BrowserController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BrowserController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rootViewController];
    [self.window addSubview: self.navigationController.view];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.rootViewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you having an xib with BrowserController class

Comment: The `rootViewController` is not getting initiated because it cannot find the `BrowserController` nib file in your bundle. Also, I think you might want to make your navigationController set as rootViewController of your `window` instead of the `BrowserController` object.

Comment: @borncrazy I don't even know what an xib file is.